# convert address to latitude and longitude in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, google-maps

I have the following code that converts address to latitude and longitude, but it works only if the input is given in single input, however i have a form that allows the user to input address, city, state and country in different lines, can anyone tell me how i can convert and save the given address into latitude and longitude

```
 <?php
    ob_start();
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","db");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())     
        {
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        }

    if($_POST)
        {
            $data_arr = geocode($_POST['address']); // get latitude, longitude and formatted address
            if($data_arr)// if able to geocode the address
                {
                    $latitude = $data_arr[0];
                    $longitude = $data_arr[1];
                    $formatted_address = $data_arr[2];
                }   
                $address = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['address']);
                $sql="INSERT INTO register_office (co_address,latitude,longitude) VALUES ('$address', '$latitude', '$longitude')";
                if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) 
                    {
                        die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
                    }
        }
    mysqli_close($con);     
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">
    </head>

    <body >
    <form action="" method="post">
        <input type='text' name='addressline1' placeholder='address line 1' />
        <input type='text' name='addressline2' placeholder='address line 2' />
        <input type='text' name='addressline3' placeholder='address line 3' />
        <input type='text' name='city' placeholder='city' />
        <input type='text' name='state' placeholder='state' />
        <input type='text' name='country' placeholder='country' />
        <input type='submit' value='Geocode!' />
    </form>

    <?php

    // function to geocode address, it will return false if unable to geocode address
    function geocode($address){

        // url encode the address
        $address = urlencode($address);

        // google map geocode api url
        $url = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address={$address}";

        // get the json response
        $resp_json = file_get_contents($url);

        // decode the json
        $resp = json_decode($resp_json, true);

        // response status will be 'OK', if able to geocode given address 
        if($resp['status']='OK'){

            // get the important data
            $lati = $resp['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat'];
            $longi = $resp['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng'];
            $formatted_address = $resp['results'][0]['formatted_address'];

            // verify if data is complete
            if($lati && $longi && $formatted_address){

                // put the data in the array
                $data_arr = array();            

                array_push(
                    $data_arr, 
                        $lati, 
                        $longi, 
                        $formatted_address
                    );

                return $data_arr;

            }else{
                return false;
            }

        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
    ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd be best to check whether the values are empty as well... After that, concatenate them using a comma `,`, like so:

```
$addressFields = array(
    $_POST['addressline1'],
    $_POST['addressline2'],
    $_POST['addressline1'],
    $_POST['city'],
    $_POST['state'],
    $_POST['country'],    
);

$addressData = implode(', ', array_filter($addressFields));
```

In this snippet, [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/array_filter) is used to filter all empty strings from the array. [`implode()`](http://php.net/implode) joins the array-items together in a string using a comma `,` as the 'glue'.
Afterwards, use the `geocode()` method as in your example:

```
$data_arr = geocode($addressData);
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the address parts together to form a single line and submit that to the Google Maps API instead.

```
$address_parts = array($addressline1, $addressline2, $addressline3, $city, $state, $country);
$address = implode(", ", $address_parts); // join the parts together divided by comma
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you should be able to concatenate your address parts together and then send that in?

E.g.

```
$address = $_POST['addressline1'] .','. $_POST['addressline2']  <<snip>> $_POST['country'];

$data_arr = geocode($address);
```

If google has trouble with repeating commas you may need to build a bit of an `if` statement to only put in the bits that are actually set (at which point building an array and imploding it will probably be better)